# Allowing node.js applications to run libpcap without sudo ("Symlink" issue )

Tags: linux, debian, node.js, pcap

I want to use the following command to allow usage of the libpcap package without to sudo (on a debian system):

```
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/nodejs
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/bin/nodejs' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

But `/usr/bin/nodejs` is not a symlink:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18M Jun  3 03:20 /usr/bin/nodejs

USER@HOST:~$ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

my drive is mounted like this:

```
USER@HOST:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
#
# /etc/fstab
#
# <device>      <mountpoint>    <filesystemtype>    <options>   <dump>  <fsckorder>
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /               ext3                defaults    0       1
```

Comment: Good to see you're trying to use capabilities, but enabling them on an interpreter is a great way to open up security vulnerabilities.

Comment: This is running in my lan only. For this reason, the security is not so important :). But if you know a better (and working) way let me know

Comment: Sure, but my comment is also for the next 10,000 people who find this question and think, "yep, that's a great solution for my Internet-facing box!".

Answer (score 0):

Check in order:

1. Double check if `/usr/bin/nodejs` is definitely a file.
2. The the capabilities are permitted for files, maybe you can not change them, even as root. Ensure the following:

   - The partition containing `/usr/bin/nodejs` is mounted rw.
   - The partition is *not* mounted using the option `nosuid`, which will prevent certain actions on the file system (The nosuid mount option specifies that the filesystem cannot contain set userid files).

Comment: 1: it is definitely a file not a symlink. 2: my drive is mounted with default options (which are the following: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async)